# __init__ not called when subcalssing dict and something else

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, built-in

Consider the following code:

```
class Lockable(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._lock = None

    def is_locked(self):
       return self._lock is None


class LockableDict(dict, Lockable):
     pass
```

And now:

```
In [2]: l = example.LockableDict(a=1, b=2, c=3)

In [3]: l.is_locked()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4344e3948b9c> in <module>()
----> 1 l.is_locked()

/home/sven/utils/example.py in is_locked(self)
      8 
      9     def is_locked(self):
---> 10         return self._lock is None

AttributeError: 'LockableDict' object has no attribute '_lock'
```

It looks as though `Lockable.__init__` weren't called at all. Is that so? Why?

To make things more interesting, it turns out that it's sufficient to change the LockableDict class header like this:

```
class LockableDict(Lockable, dict):
```

to make it work. Why?

Comment: If you don't call it, it's not called.

Comment: What do you mean? I don't override `__init__` in `LockableDict`, so it should generate an `__init__` making automatic calls to base classes' `__init__`s, shouldn't it? Also it doesn't explain why the second variant works...

Comment: You should explicit call `__init__` in the `__init__` of LockableDict

Comment: No, that's the way C++ does, but not Python.

Comment: Then why does it work after the modification I described?

Comment: @RvdK: I think this is a different question; that OP understands how Python works, and wanted to know why it was designed that way; this one doesn't understand, and wants to know what's happening.

Comment: If the subclass inherits from only ONE parent and if the subclass does not define its own constructor, the parent's constructor will be inherited and used when instantiating the subclass. From your experiments with subclassing from multiple parents, it appears that Python takes the first parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your misunderstanding is clear from this comment:

> I don't override `__init__` in `LockableDict`, so it should generate an `__init__` making automatic calls to base classes' `__init__`s, shouldn't it?

No!

First, nothing gets automatically generated; the method resolution happens at call time.

And at call time, Python won't call *every* base class's `__init__`, it will only call the first one it finds.<sup>*</sup>

This is why `super` exists. If you don't explicitly call `super` in an override, no base classes *or even sibling classes* will get their implementations called. And `dict.__init__` doesn't call its `super`.

Neither does your `Lockable.__init__`. So, this means that reversing the order makes sure `Lockable.__init__` gets called… but `dict.__init__` now *doesn't* get called.

---

So, what do you actually want to do? Well, Python's MRO algorithm is designed to allow maximum flexibility for hierarchies of *cooperating* classes, with any non-cooperating classes thrown in at the end. So, you could do this:

```
class Lockable(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # super(Lockable, self).__init__() for 2.x
        self._lock = None

    def is_locked(self):
       return self._lock is None


class LockableDict(Lockable, dict):
     pass
```

Also notice that this allows you to pass initializer arguments along the chain through all your cooperating classes, and then just call the unfriendly class's `__init__` with the arguments you know it needs.

In a few cases, you have to put an unfriendly class first.<sup>**</sup> In that case, you have to explicitly call around them:

```
class LockableDict(dict, Lockable):
    def __init__(self):
        dict.__init__(self)
        Lockable.__init__(self)
```

But fortunately, this doesn't come up very often.

---

<sub>* In standard [method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/), which is slightly more complicated than you'd expect. The same MRO rule is applied when you call `super` to find the "next" class—which may be a base class, or a sibling, or even a sibling of a subclass. You may find the Wikipedia article on [C3 linearization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization) more approachable.</sub>

<sub>** Especially for built-in classes, because they're special in a few ways that aren't worth getting into here. Then again, many built-in classes don't actually do anything in their `__init__`, and instead do all the initialization inside the `__new__` constructor.</sub>

Comment: Is there any gain from Python not calling *all* `__init__`s but only the first one it finds? I see none...

Comment: @Sventimir Yes. For just one advantage: imagine that Lockable is later changed to need an extra argument that dict won't accept. If Python automatically called every base class, your code could no longer work. For more details, read the links I posted in the footnotes and the answer to the related question RvdK linked in a comment on your question. (Because this followup basically is a dup of that related question.)